# nginx deploying multiple sevices (ports) on one docker

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm struggling for three days now for my nginx config, therefore maybe someone can help...

My situation now:

nginx reverse proxy <--> one VM with one DOCKER which hosts multiple services on different ports (9000 to 9005).

If i test the docker build locally with 127.0.0.1 url instead of public domain everything works fine. If i try to run with https or even https on nginx i fail.

Failings means, i can connect to my docker service 9001 (which is login service), i login into app and than there is a respone again over http  and this request does not go through nginx.

My service configuration on VM/Docker

Service 9001 does have the prefix /auth
Service 9002 does have the prefix /dashboard

A request looks like: http://sub.domain/auth or http://sub.domain/dashboard

on Nginx i'm searching for this prefix and therefore make a route to the
correct service like so:

```
server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name sub.domain;

        location /auth/ {
                proxy_pass http://172.18.1.25:9001;

                proxy_read_timeout 300s;

                # proxy header
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
                proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        }

        location /dashboard/ {
                proxy_pass http://172.18.1.25:9002;

                proxy_read_timeout 300s;

                # proxy header
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
                proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        }

        location /device/ {
                proxy_pass http://172.18.1.25:9005;

                proxy_read_timeout 300s;

                # proxy header
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
                proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        }
}
```

** update **
Testet without nginx (direct open ports to vm ports) same problem.

--> next Test without docker. Running Services directly on my vm...pending